# Google map keep geting a blank screen on android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

need some help here please.

I have an guide app on AppStore and i'm  trying to build the same app for android but i have some problems with Google Maps, keep geting a blank screen.

-I have follow instructions from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start.

This what i have done so far.

-Have install Eclipse Keytool

-Have added Google Play Services Library in the project

-Have great SHA1 figerprint

-Have great Key for Android apps (with certificates) form Google Developer

-Past the key in manifest.xml

-Have delete the google-play-services-remove.jar from the lib file.

Have no errors or warnings when i test my app on a real device, but i have this red lines in my LogCat:

```
(Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.cyououtandroid, API Key: AIzaSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGkyAxg, Certificate Fingerprint: DF6E6EXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0F2E5)
```

Im sure that im missing something but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Check the Following Things 1st

- you have added Debug SHA1 key (for testing)
- You have added Release SHA1 key (key generated from Signed apk for release)

  Your combination of Package to Key is incorrect thats why you are getting authentication failed.

**Note:** Don not remove the Maps.jar from your java build Path & google play serivce lib.

Comment: How do i get Debug SHA1 key (for testing)?

Comment: Can you please tell, in pace of release SHA1 key must i set the Debug SHA1 key in manifest.xml file? If yes, where can i found the debug SHA1 key?

Comment: have a look at a foolowing tutorial you always have a "Debug.keystore" that is generic for all application and the other key store is that which with which you sign your apk when ever you need to run and test your map you have to add your deb key in your manifest file and then check and if you want to test it after siging apk then before signing apk you should add the release  SHA1 key and then sign the APK 
here is the tutorial 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/

Comment: you need to add 2 seperate finger prints 1 with your package name and your debug SHA1 key and the other with your other key store in Google API console

Comment: THANK YOU, i did not know about the debug key. My maps are working perfect now. You was a big help.. Thanks again...

Comment: If this really worked with you then mark it correct so that it can help others having same issues

Comment: Hi. im new to this forum, i don't know how it works im looking in it now.

Answer (score 2):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And make sure following steps done correct or not:

Steps:
* to ensure that device has Google Play services APK
* to install Google Play Service rev. more than 2

[image]

- to create project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- to enable "Google Maps Android API v2"
  [image]
- to register of SHA1 in project (**NOW, YOU NEED WRITE SHA1;your.app.package.name**) at APIs console and get API KEY
- to copy directory ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib to root of your project
- to add next line to the YOUR_PROJECT/project.properties

`android.library.reference.1=google-play-services_lib`

- to add next lines to the YOUR_PROJECT/proguard-project.txt

`-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {`

`protected Object[][] getContents();`

`}`

Okay, now you ready to create your own Google Map app with using Google Map APIs V2 for Android.

If you create application with min SDK = 8, please use android support library v4 + SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

After got this let me know.

Follow this step by step process to get map in v2:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not generating the API key properly.

When you generate the key , make sure you have "SHA1;packagename" separated by a ";".

Also make sure you have maps.jar and google-play-services.jar in your build path.

*maps.jar - /android-sdk/add-ons/google-apis-(whichever version)/libs/maps.jar*

*google-play-services - android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs*

Comment: Thank you for your replay. im sure that i have set the SHA1 key correct. but i don't see the maps.jar in the /libs file there is only the gcm.jar. what am i missing here???